# Default popup no working when pressing the extension icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, brave-browser

I am trying to make a simple extension, that save whatever text is selected.
For now, i just created the UI.

I have an html file called `popup.html` linked to a css file. That works alright when trying it with live server.
Here's the `manifest.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "Save Things",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "Mohammed Hazem Hassine",
    "action": {
        "default-popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Saving extension thingy"
    },
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "script.js"
    }
}
```

the `script.js` file contains a simple `console.log("extension loaded");`
the extension seems to be loaded but when i click the icon the popup doesn't show.
[Picture of the added extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1mw5.png). I'm using the brave browser by the way but i think that isn't an issue.

#### What am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

This is my first stack overflow question, any advice regarding that will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to change your file name from popup.html to index.html

Comment: It turns out that i have a typo in the manifest.json file , where i wrote "default-popup" instead of "default_popup". thanks anyways